# CLLocationManager works with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

All I'm trying to do is get the current position of the User, and show on the map of my app, so I am using CLLocationManager class, as anybody can see below:

**ViewController.h**

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MeuPrimeiroViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>{

    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;


@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    //Lendo as coordenadas com o core location
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {

        NSLog(@"CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled == ON");

            self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            self.locationManager.delegate = self;

            self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    }else{

        NSLog(@"CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled == OFF");
    }


}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    CLLocationDistance altitude = newLocation.altitude;
    CLLocationDegrees latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"Altitude, Latitude, Longitude: %f, %f, %f",altitude,latitude,longitude);

    MKCoordinateRegion coordenada = {{0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};

    coordenada.center.latitude = latitude;
    coordenada.center.longitude = longitude;

    [mapView setRegion:coordenada animated:YES];

    //Calculando distancias

    CLLocationDistance distancia = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
    NSLog(@"Distancia em metros : %f",distancia);

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);

}
```

The problem with this code is that my methods of CLLocationManager class not being called, I did some research on the internet over a possible problem related to the ARC, but none of them worked, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you specified the location usage description in your Info.plist?

Comment: What methods are not being called and how do you know?

Answer (score 2):

iOS 8 changed 2 things that make this not work as it did before

1. On iOS 8, you need to call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization` before calling `startUpdatingLocation`
2. You MUST provide a location usage description corresponding to what type of authorization you are requesting in the Info.plist (either `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`). You should also continue to provide the value for the old pre-iOS 8 key (`NSLocationUsageDescription`) as a fallback for older versions of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

> All I'm trying to do is get the current position of the User, and show on the map of my app

You do not need any of that in order to put the user's location on a map. Just tell the map to track the user's location. In iOS 8 you do need user authorization to do this, and for that you do need a location manager. But these two lines of code are sufficient (this is Swift but I'm sure you can translate):

```
self.locman.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
self.map.userTrackingMode = .Follow
```

Comment: Hey I have a mapView in my viewController and in attributes inspector this map is checked (shows user location), I do all of they you say in your post, but Im receiving this message in console:

Comment: Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.......But Im calling after the updateLocations, and when my app start I'm not receiving the message to user authorization...why?

Comment: Uncheck it in the attributes inspector. Do it in code as I showed you.